# Get LCSK (Live Chat Starter Kit) to always be expanded, or do so at page_load

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net

I'm trying to incorporate [LCSK](https://github.com/dstpierre/lcsk) into my website. Since it requires .net 4.5 and my site is on 4.0, and can't upgrade ATM, I'm trying a workaround, host the chat on a separate sub domain on it's own app. Then I have it iframed inside [ajax collapsible pane](http://www.newschool.edu/ajax/CollapsiblePanel/CollapsiblePanel.aspx)l into my website. The problem is once you expand the ajax Panel, you still need to click the "Chat with us" blue bar to start the actual chat. I'd assume i need some sort of javascript to simulate an on_load.click, or to run the functions for me, but can't seam to get it to work.I tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#chat-box-header").click();
});
```

But it didn't work, and similar with no success.

The main action happens trough this [.js file](https://github.com/dstpierre/lcsk/blob/master/src/nuget/content/LCSK/chat.js)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick just fine:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
LCSKChat.config();
LCSKChat.init();
$("#chat-box-header").click();
});
```

I'd need to hide the blue bar, and iFrame or include the link with the chat page only when the user clicks my ajax bar, but other than that, this trick would allow you to add the chat to sites that are 4.0 or less (IF you can host separate web app with the chat only).